# zmv: Replace double-quote (") in filename

Tags: zsh, rename, replace

Using zmv on macOS, I'd like to replace double-quotes (") in filenames with underscores (_). However, I'm having trouble getting the zshexpn to correctly isolate the ". Is there some magical zsh/zmv/zshexpn option I should be using?

```
% zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${(S)2//"/_}'
zmv: syntax error in replacement
% zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${(S)2//\"/_}'
zmv: syntax error in replacement`
% zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${(Sp)2//\"/_}'
zmv: syntax error in replacement
```

(This is part of a much larger replace-illegal-characters engagement. I'm hoping to use one zmv expression to do the whole thing.)

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how `zmv` handles the second expression exactly, but the using a variable to contain the quote seems to work:

```
quote='"'
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//$quote/_}'
```

Example:

```
% find
.
./bar
./bar/Hello, "World".

% zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//$quote/_}'
mv -- 'bar/Hello, "World".' 'bar/Hello, _World_.'
```

Comment: It handles it with the `e` parameter expansion flag (combined with `X` to report parsing errors): look for `${(Xe)repl}` in that function. It looks like a bug/limitation with the way that `e` flag works. Another way to work around it is to have `${2//$'\x22'/_}` in the replacement.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'd tried using an `\x22` trick, but couldn't get it to evaluate.  Given the replacement is already single-quoted, how would you enable the evaluation of `$\x22` within the substition?  (Are you assuming `noglob` is in place?)

Comment: @atlauren, something like `zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//$'\''\x22'\''/_}'` or `zmv -n '(**/)(*)' "\$1\${2//\$'\x22/_}"`(not pretty).

Answer (score 2):

In my testing `zmv '* *' '$f:gs/"/_'` worked fine.

https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_2.html is a **very** dry explanation of file globbing. Not the same as regular expressions but close enough to be confusing.

Comment: That section of *An Introduction to the Z Shell*  you link is not very relevant as the `:s` modifier doesn't use globbing patterns (just fixed strings) unless you set the `histsubstpattern` option (though see [the new `:S` modifier in the next version of zsh](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00545.html)). https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers for the documentation about modifiers in the manual (or `info zsh modifiers` on your system for your version of zsh).

Answer (score 2):

It is a parsing error.... If you edit the `zmv` function and remove the `2> /dev/null` after `g=${(Xe)repl}` that Stéphane mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767083/zmv-replace-double-quote-in-filename#comment1463408_767087) you get an additional error message:

```
zmv:257: parse error
zmv: syntax error in replacement
```

I guess the parse error is due to `zsh` expecting a closing double-quote because the following works just fine:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//"\""/_}'
```